# MAUI SplashScreen SVG doesn't resize

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022, maui

I'm trying to use MAUI built-in splash screen generator. No matter what parameters I use, output is the same (very small). I'm trying to let it take all available space (contain mode).

Csproj file:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="FFAAAA"/>
```

I tried:

- different BaseSize values
- changing width/height inside SVG
- changing viewport inside SVG

[image]

Source SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="1024" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 456 456" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
    <path d="m 105.50037,281.60863 c -2.70293,0 -5.00091,-0.90042 -6.893127,-2.70209 -1.892214,-1.84778 -2.837901,-4.04181 -2.837901,-6.58209 0,-2.58722 0.945687,-4.80389 2.837901,-6.65167 1.892217,-1.84778 4.190197,-2.77167 6.893127,-2.77167 2.74819,0 5.06798,0.92389 6.96019,2.77167 1.93749,1.84778 2.90581,4.06445 2.90581,6.65167 0,2.54028 -0.96832,4.73431 -2.90581,6.58209 -1.89221,1.80167 -4.212,2.70209 -6.96019,2.70209 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="M 213.56111,280.08446 H 195.99044 L 149.69953,207.0544 c -1.17121,-1.84778 -2.14037,-3.76515 -2.90581,-5.75126 h -0.40578 c 0.36051,2.12528 0.54076,6.67515 0.54076,13.6496 v 65.13172 h -15.54349 v -99.36009 h 18.71925 l 44.7374,71.29798 c 1.89222,2.95695 3.1087,4.98917 3.64945,6.09751 h 0.26996 c -0.45021,-2.6325 -0.67573,-7.09015 -0.67573,-13.37293 v -64.02256 h 15.47557 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="m 289.25134,280.08446 h -54.40052 v -99.36009 h 52.23835 v 13.99669 h -36.15411 v 28.13085 h 33.31621 v 13.9271 h -33.31621 v 29.37835 h 38.31628 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
    <path d="M 366.56466,194.72106 H 338.7222 v 85.3634 h -16.08423 v -85.3634 h -27.77455 v -13.99669 h 71.70124 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.838376" />
</svg>
```

Comment: **1)** a .svg contains what looks like xml. Open it in a text editor. Add that xml to question.  **2)** You mention setting base size. Add what you tried to question **3)** Use an editor to "save as" .png. What are the pixel dimensions of the resulting .png? (Presumably, small, just like the image you show.)

Comment: Added SWG XML. Tried BaseSize from 128,128 to 1024,1024. Saving as PNG give large picture, much larger than PNG I used in Xamarin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `known issue` and it's been tracked in [MauiSplashScreen resizetizering issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11160).You can follow up it. Also, on `Android`, the splash screen image is limited in **size** and cannot be set to any arbitrary value, you can check this :https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen for more details.

Thanks for your feedback and patience!